# pure as3 benefits to compiling with flex4 instead of flex3?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

If I have a pure as3 project that I have been compiling with flex3 from mxmlc, is there any reason to switch to using the mxmlc with flex4?

I can use all of the flash 10 language features like Vector, 3D, etc., so that is not a reason to switch (or is there something I can't do?).

But maybe there is a performance boost?  Or is it the exact same compiling tool and the flex code base is the only difference?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler in Flex 4 is much faster even for pure AS3 projects.

http://www.duvos.com/?p=47

Other than compiler speed, I'm not aware of any differences.  The resulting SWF/SWC should be pretty much identical.